# Error when browsing a newly deployed MVC app on IIS 7: Http 500 and custom errors not set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, web-deployment

I do have custom errors on in the web.config file that sits in the root directory of my MVC project.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/UnauthorizedAccess" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

However, when I deploy the project in IIS 7, any attempt to browse the web application produces this error in the browser:

```
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error 
settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being 
viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers 
running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote 
machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file 
located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> 
tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by 
modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration 
tag to point to a custom error page URL.    

    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

In my app, I have handled errors and logged them and also emailed a few team members. All of that works when I run the app in Visual Studio or locally. But when I browse this newly deployed app, no log is created, nor am I sent any email.

**Update**

The funny thing is, it does go to my application's error handler. I know this because the address bar reads:

```
http://10.1.17.43/MyApp/Error?aspxerrorpath=/MyApp
```

where `Error` is a controller (`ErrorController`) in my application that handles all exceptions.

Comment: I would try setting `<customErrors mode="Off" />` just to see what the  underlying error message is. It might be some sort of configuration error. Have you tried that?

Comment: If it is getting to the error handler, then there is probably an exception occurring on the error handling page itself.

Comment: Thank you, rsbarro. You're a star! That worked! One of my dependencies couldn't load. Now, that's a new problem but at least we're a step ahead. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. Mind if I post that an answer?

Comment: Not at all. In fact, I was going to say that myself. Please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would try setting `<customErrors mode="Off" />`, just to see what the underlying error message is. It might be some sort of configuration error.

Since the application's error page is being called, there is most likely an error occurring on the error page itself. Setting `<customErrors mode="Off" />` will let you see what that error is.